# Hide or Remove jquery ui tab based on condition

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

Html:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    Tab1 Contain
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
   Tab2 Contain
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
   tab3 contain
  </div>
</div>
```

What I try on js :

```
var id="A"; 
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
if(id==="A")
{
     $( "#tabs-2" ).tabs( "option", "hide", { effect: "explode", duration: 1000 } );
    //$('#ui-id-2').hide();

}
```

Sample [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shree/eN9We/).

I want to hide or remove particular tab if condition is met.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var id = "A";
$("#tabs").tabs();
if (id === "A") {
    $('#tabs > ul li:has(a[href="#tabs-1"])').hide()
    $("#tabs").tabs('refresh');
    $("#tabs").tabs('option', 'active', 1);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/75dpn)